# Is it possible to get details with the Android Studio lint tool?

Tags: build.gradle, android-lint

I use lint to check an Android app project:

```
gradlew lint
```

It shows the following:

```
> Task :app:compileOfficialDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

The process generates two files: lint-results.html and lint-results.xml.   I checked both files, but could not find any information related to deprecated API.  Is it possible to generate more details about deprecated API in these two files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example "build.gradle" I marked up:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.boxpik.android"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 19
    ...
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:all"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
...
```

In this example, I added `options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:all"` to `build.gradle`.

This gave me a bunch of Lint warning in my Android Studio "Build" window:

```
                          ^
C:\xyz\PoolToScoreDetailFragment.java:55: warning: [deprecation] ProgressDialog in android.app has been deprecated
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
            ^
C:\xyz\PoolToScoreDetailFragment.java:346: warning: [deprecation] ProgressDialog in android.app has been deprecated
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(application);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It works for showing the details for my project.  I was thinking about using  "gradlew lint" as plan A, and it could not work I would go to the project building route as plan B.   I will accept your answer if no answer isprovided for using "gradlew lint".  This is because I need these details only occasionally.

Comment: "Lint" and the "Java Compiler" are separate tools.  Both can be run from Gradle.  "-Xlint" is a Java compiler command line option. It's the guy who gives you the "detailed messages".  I'm not saying you *can't* run both tools from the same Gradle task, but from my perspective it's easier just to add `options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:all"` to build.gradle when I want it, and comment it out when I don't.

Comment: Thank you for the elucidation.  I did not know they are two different things.  This also explains why AS's code analysis does not show the deprecated APIs which made me scratch my head a moment ago.